# Error partial not showing messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The following code is  in a partial named **errors.blade.php**:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
@endif
```

It's being called in **master.blade.php**:

```
<body>
    @include("layouts.nav")

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        @include("layouts.sidebar")

        @yield("content")
        @include("layouts.errors")
      </div>
    </div>
    @include("layouts.footer")
  </body>
```

After submitting a form and using the **validate()** function, nothing is shown on the page that a user is redirected to. If I take the code from **errors.blade.php** and put it directly into the **products.index.blade.php** file, the errors show as intended. This is not desirable as I want errors and partials of a similar nature to be shown across all views if applicable.

Why aren't they working?

Answer (score 0):

I see what mean and I do the same but instead of in master I only include it in the page that need it like form pages, login and registration.